# Can I use useEffect in React to update page display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use useEffect to update the DOM whenever a certain state or prop updates. The console logs my tests when I want the DOM update to fire, but the DOM update or render never occurs

I've tried to figure out ways to make a conditional statement that would check if the prop or state I want the useEffect to fire on has changed, but since the function is running my console logs, but not my render, there has to be something I'm missing.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Report( { weatherData, units }) {

    let windUnits = 'mph';

    useEffect(() => {
        units == 'imperial' ? windUnits = 'mph' : windUnits = 'km/h';
        console.log('units updated');
    }, [ weatherData ]);

    return (
        <p id="wind">{ `${ weatherData.wind.speed }${ windUnits } ${ getWindDirection(weatherData.wind.deg) }`}</p>
    )
}

export default Report;
```

The units are from the parent component and can be changed by two buttons to receive differently measured data. weatherData is the data received from an api, when the api is called and the data changes, the windUnits should change according to the type of units specified.

Currently, while the console.log works and the correct unit type is printed to the console from the parent component, the text on the screen doesn't change to match it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the component is rerendered whenever the props (`weatherData`, `units`) change, you don't need to use an effect. Just assign the correct unit to `windUnits`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const getWindDirection = x => x;

const Report = ({ weatherData, units }) => {
  const windUnits = units == 'imperial' ? 'mph' : 'km/h';

  return (
    <p id="wind">{ `${ weatherData.wind.speed }${ windUnits } ${ getWindDirection(weatherData.wind.deg) }`}</p>
  );
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [units, setUnits] = useState('imperial');
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('imperial')}>imperial</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('metric')}>metric</button>
      
      <Report weatherData={{ wind: { speed: 10, deg: 45 }}} units={units} />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  demo
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you want to rerender the component only on `windData` change, you can use `useEffect` with `useState`. `useEffect` handles side effects, and doesn't rerender the component, and the change to the variable will be lost on the next render. `useState` on the other hand will rerender the component.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const getWindDirection = x => x;

const Report = ({ weatherData, units }) => {
  const [windUnits, setWindUnits] = useState('mph');

  useEffect(() => {
    setWindUnits(units == 'imperial' ? 'mph' : 'km/h');
  }, [weatherData]);

  return (
    <p id="wind">{ `${ weatherData.wind.speed }${ windUnits } ${ getWindDirection(weatherData.wind.deg) }`}</p>
  );
};

const windData = { wind: { speed: 10, deg: 45 }};

const Demo = () => {
  const [units, setUnits] = useState('imperial');
  const [data, setData] = useState(windData);
  
  const changeSpeed = () => setData({ ...data, wind: { ...data.wind, speed: Math.random() * 100 }});
    
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('imperial')}>imperial</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('metric')}>metric</button>
      <button onClick={changeSpeed}>Change speed</button>
      
      <Report weatherData={data} units={units} />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  demo
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Another option is to use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) with the `areEqual` callback, and only check for `weatherData` equality:

```js
const { useState, memo } = React;

const getWindDirection = x => x;

const Report = memo(({ weatherData, units }) => {
  const windUnits = units == 'imperial' ? 'mph' : 'km/h';

  return (
    <p id="wind">{ `${ weatherData.wind.speed }${ windUnits } ${ getWindDirection(weatherData.wind.deg) }`}</p>
  );
}, ({ weatherData: prev }, { weatherData: current }) => prev === current);

const windData = { wind: { speed: 10, deg: 45 }};

const Demo = () => {
  const [units, setUnits] = useState('imperial');
  const [data, setData] = useState(windData);
  
  const changeSpeed = () => setData({ ...data, wind: { ...data.wind, speed: Math.random() * 100 }});
    
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('imperial')}>imperial</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnits('metric')}>metric</button>
      <button onClick={changeSpeed}>Change speed</button>
      
      <Report weatherData={data} units={units} />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  demo
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: That does work in changing the display, but not when I want it to. The only time I want the units display to change is when the weatherData is updated, not when the units prop is updated.

Comment: See added answers * 2.

Comment: Thank you so much, the second solution is just what I'm looking for!

Comment: Great. Although I prefer the memo - less code, and rerenders.